# Keyboard stopped working on desktop with win7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, hardware-failure, desktop

Keyboard was working until the last time i shut down my PC. When i turned it on keyboard didn't respond. Led lights do light up at the start but i still can't use it during boot up. I was looking for a solution on various sites but nothing helped. Some of those included downloading drivers, deleting registry an the classic unplug and plug, both with PC on and off.

I don't have another keyboard. And it's not USB.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Have you tried a different keyboard? If it is a USB keyboard, have you tried a different port?

Comment: I don't have another keyboard. And it's not usb

Comment: OK. Shut down the PC. Unplug it from power completely. Leave it sit like this for about 15 minutes. Then hold the power button for 30 seconds. Plug it back into power and turn it on. Does the keyboard work now?

Comment: Now it works during boot up and a bit after that but then it just stops working

Comment: I hope you have a backup of your registry.

Comment: @CharlieRB i don't

Comment: Please edit you question reflecting all the steps you did mentioned in your comments - it will be easier to help you.